# Choose a random method from a class

Tags: python, list, class, random

I have a class with some functions, like this:

```
class valami:

    def a():
        *some code...*
    def b():
        *some code...*
    def c():
        *some code...*
```

I want to choose a random function from the `valami` calss. I already tried this:

```
random.choice((valami.a(), valami.b(), valami.c()))
```

But it called all the functions at same time.

Comment: This happens because `valami.a` is the name of the actual function and will return that function as an object. `valami.a()` will **call** that function and return the **result** of calling the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call them right away, only call the function that the code randomly chose:

```
random.choice((valami.a, valami.b, valami.c))()
```

If you don't want to call it yet, just remove the pair of parenthesis at the end, make it become:

```
random.choice((valami.a, valami.b, valami.c))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `operator.methodcaller` along with `random.choice`

```
methodcaller(choice(('a', 'b', 'c'))(valami)
```

To delay calling just make the `methodcaller` beforehand.

```
method = methodcaller(choice(('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

You can even get the method names from somewhere else:

```
methods = 'a', 'b', 'c'
method = methodcaller(choice(methods))
```

Then just call the method on the class/instance:

```
method(valami)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose between the functions first and then call the chosen function.

```
random.choice((valami.a, valami.b, valami.c))()
```